# Store multiline output on bash array

Tags: bash

I am trying to store the output of this:

```
mdfind "kMDItemContentType == 'com.apple.application-bundle'"
```

Output is like this:

```
/Applications/Safari.app
/Applications/Xcode.app
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Accessibility Inspector.app
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/RealityComposer.app
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/FileMerge.app
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Create ML.app
```

I try to store it as an array but the contents are split per spaces:

```
bash-5.1$ arr=( $(/usr/bin/mdfind "kMDItemContentType == 'com.apple.application-bundle'") )
bash-5.1$ echo ${arr[2]}
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Accessibility
bash-5.1$ echo ${arr[3]}
Inspector.app
bash-5.1$
```

So how can I do the trick?

Comment: Use `readarray` aka `mapfile` (see the [manual](https://helpmanual.io/builtin/readarray/))

Comment: Also, use the `-0` option to use a null byte, rather than a newline, to mark the end of  a path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `readarray` and process substitution to read a null-delimited series of paths into an array.

```
readarray -d '' arr < <(mdfind -0 "...")
```

The `-0` option tells `mdfind` to terminate each path with a null byte instead of a linefeed. (This guards agains rare, but legal, path names that include linefeeds. Null bytes are not a valid character for any path component.)

The `-d ''` option tells `readarray` to treat the null byte as the end of a "line".

`readarray` populates an array with one "line" of input per element. The input is the output of `mdfind`; the process substitution ensures that `readarray` executes in the current shell, not a subshell induced by a pipe like

```
mdfind -0 "..." | readarray -d '' arr
```

(Under some situations, you *can* make the last job of a pipeline execute in the current shell; that's beyond the scope of this answer, though.)

---

Example:

```
# Using printf to simulate mdfind -0
$ readarray -d '' arr < <(printf 'foo\nbar\000baz\000')
$ declare -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]=$'foo\nbar' [1]="baz")
```